# What the '-DNSIG=_NSIG' in gcc option do?

Tags: gcc

When I was compiling the source code of TET3.8 of open group, one of the compile command is below,

```
gcc -I../inc -I../../../inc/tet3 -DNSIG=_NSIG -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500 -DINETD   -O -c host.c
```

What do the '-DNSIG=_NSIG' represent? I could not find it in the gcc helping files.
Any suggestion about this will be good.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It defines an macro called NSIG with the value _NSIG.

-DINETD defines a macro called INETD but with the value 1.

They are used by the preprocessor, for example

```
#ifdef INET
```

will evaluate to true if -DINET was on the command line, but false if not.

Comment: This is a macro definition, not an environment variable!